# gpg2: no secret key

Tags: encryption, gnupg, gpg-agent

I've been using enigmail for over a year without issue, and today it doesn't work.

I found the following interesting fact:

```
gpg --decrypt something.gpg # this works
gpg2 --decrypt something.gpg # this fails
```

So something is broken with gpg version 2 on my machine.

This led me to see that:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys # reads from ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
gpg2 --list-secret-keys # reads from ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg (pubring?!)
```

This seems to be the root of the problem... of course `gpg2` can't find the secret key because it's looking in the wrong file.

How could my `gpg2` fail when my `gpg` works fine?  I don't see any options to specify where the secret keys are read from.

Anybody have any ideas?

---

**Response to @grawity**:

Thanks, I appreciate your help.  I ran `strace`, and I see what you are talking about.

However, even after `gpg2 --import ...` I am seeing no difference in behavior.  I can only get it to work if I reboot (without starting gpg-agent), run `gpg2 --import ...`, then run `gpg2 --decrypt ...`.  After that sequence, thunderbird + enigmail also behaves nicely.  However, after 15 minutes or so (my guess is the password I entered to decrypt has expired), then `gpg-agent` is back to its old behavior.  This sequence is repeatable.

So here is some output if it helps clear anything up:

output of `gpg2 -K`:

```
/home/<username>/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
---------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/AAAAAAAA <date> [SC]
uid         [ultimate] <description of me>
ssb   rsa4096/BBBBBBBB <date> [E]
```

output of `gpg-connect-agent`

```
> keyinfo --list
S KEYINFO <keygrip associated with AAAAAAAA> D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO <keygrip associated with BBBBBBBB> D - - - P - - -
OK
```

output of `gpg2 -v -r <my email> -e testfile`

```
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: using subkey BBBBBBBB instead of primary key AAAAAAAA
gpg: This key belongs to us
gpg: reading from 'testfile'
gpg: writing to 'testfile.gpg'
gpg: RSA/AES256 encrypted for: "BBBBBBBB <description of me>"
```

output of `gpg2 -v -d testfile.gpg`

```
gpg: public key is BBBBBBBB
gpg: using subkey BBBBBBBB instead of primary key AAAAAAAA
gpg: using subkey BBBBBBBB instead of primary key AAAAAAAA
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID BBBBBBBB, created <date>
      "<description of me>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. The needed to use `gpg-agent`, and the pinentry program needed to be set to `pinentry-gtk-2`. Before it was set to `pinentry-gnome3`, which existed on my system, but it didn't work. I had to manually install `pinentry-gtk-2`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> …of course gpg2 can't find the secret key because it's looking in the wrong file.

That's not the *only* file it's looking at.

In GnuPG 1.x (and 2.0), the "secring" used to have a duplicate copy of your keyblock's public data as well, so it was entirely self-contained (and the only difference between `gpg -k` and `gpg -K` was which file it'd read), but at the same time more difficult for the program to maintain.

In GnuPG 2.1, secret keys are now stored independently – they're maintained by *gpg-agent*, which keeps them in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/`. So both `gpg -k` and `gpg -K` now have to read the OpenPGP information from the pubring, but the latter additionally asks *gpg-agent* about which certificates have associated secret keys. If you're using *strace*, you should notice a `connect()` call right after reading the pubring.

If GnuPG didn't automatically migrate the keys, just import the whole secring directly:

```
gpg2 --import ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

To check the agent's contents manually:

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 
> keyinfo --list
S KEYINFO 926145FFCA32B3E6E079A0CF73EA77C40733A349 D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO BACFB81EAFC864F4AB2926E8B1F55AD579F78D1A D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO FF3D1DD51B9C79E148CCCEA5F7F3E25EC96048B7 D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO 4D29EF1460F164CDB11D0FC0247214660ACDD60F D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO 06B13685B9AA429B9CABCE480930D74B991C8DF0 D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO B28DB8D045654E8A6A40466A07FCD9E432935E29 D - - - P - - -
OK
> /bye
$
```

These are "keygrips" – compare them with GnuPG's secring:

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip
/home/fred/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------
sec   ed25519 2018-08-18 [SC]
      2357E133AD5D24F6CB2C1B0CEF4F7ED27E252632
      Keygrip = 4D29EF1460F164CDB11D0FC0247214660ACDD60F 
uid           [ultimate] Fred Foobar <fred@example.com>
```

Comment: I had the same problem: I tried to generate a key usign `gpg --gen-key` that I wanted to use with `gopass`. Unfortunately, `gopass` uses `gpg2`...
`gpg2 --import` worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: For me `gpg2 --import ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` fixed it.

Comment: You're my heroo

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I decided the issue was that I was using Debian Unstable and there was a version mismatch introduced by an `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  I suppose that is why they call it "Unstable".

Comment: I have it in Ubuntu LTS too. After switching from Ubuntu Unity to GNOME.